# django ajax/jquery file upload

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to replicate the example given by Alex Kuhl on his excellent post: http://kuhlit.blogspot.com/2011/04/ajax-file-uploads-and-csrf-in-django-13.html

However, I am not too successful in replicating this.

```
####### upload_page.html  

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}Blog Post: Upload Files.{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<div id="maintext"> 
<p>To upload a file, click on the button below.</p>
<div id="file-uploader">
<noscript>
<p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
<!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
</noscript>
</div>
<script>
    function createUploader(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader( {
        action: "{% url ajax_upload %}",
        element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
        multiple: false,
        onComplete: function( id, fileName, responseJSON ) {
          if( responseJSON.success )
        alert( "success!" ) ;
          else
        alert( "Sorry, your upload has failed! Please contact us by telephone or email." ) ;
        },
        onAllComplete: function( uploads ) {
          // uploads is an array of maps
          // the maps look like this: { file: FileObject, response: JSONServerResponse }
          alert( "All complete!" ) ;
        },
        params: {
          'csrf_token': '{{ csrf_token }}',
          'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
          'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
        },
      } ) ;
    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // don't wait for the window to load
    window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The views.py is as follows:

```
############### views.py
def upload_page( request ):
    ctx = RequestContext( request, {
        'csrf_token': get_token( request ),
    })
    return render_to_response( 'success/upload_page.html', ctx )

def save_upload( uploaded, filename, raw_data ):
    filename = settings.UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR
    '''
    raw_data: if True, uploaded is an HttpRequest object with the file being
        the raw post data
        if False, uploaded has been submitted via the basic form
        submission and is a regular Django UploadedFile in request.FILES
    '''
    try:
        from io import FileIO, BufferedWriter
        with BufferedWriter( FileIO( filename, "wb" ) ) as dest:
            # if the "advanced" upload, read directly from the HTTP request
            # with the Django 1.3 functionality
            if raw_data:
                foo = uploaded.read( 1024 )
                while foo:
                    dest.write( foo )
                    foo = uploaded.read( 1024 )
            # if not raw, it was a form upload so read in the normal Django chunks fashion
            else:
                for c in uploaded.chunks( ):
                    dest.write( c )
            # got through saving the upload, report success
            return True
    except IOError:
        # could not open the file most likely
        pass
        return False

def ajax_upload( request ):
    if request.method == "POST":   
        if request.is_ajax( ):
            # the file is stored raw in the request
            upload = request
            is_raw = True
            # AJAX Upload will pass the filename in the querystring if it is the "advanced" ajax upload
            try:
                filename = request.GET[ 'qqfile' ]
            except KeyError:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest( "AJAX request not valid" )
        # not an ajax upload, so it was the "basic" iframe version with submission via form
        else:
            is_raw = False
            if len( request.FILES ) == 1:
                upload = request.FILES.values( )[ 0 ]
            else:
                raise Http404( "Bad Upload" )
            filename = upload.name

        # save the file
        success = save_upload( upload, filename, is_raw )

        # let Ajax Upload know whether we saved it or not
        import json
        ret_json = { 'success': success, }
        return HttpResponse( json.dumps( ret_json ) )
```

The urls.py is as follows:

####### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':   settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^$', index,name='home'),
url( r'^ajax_upload$', ajax_upload, name="ajax_upload" ),
url( r'^upload/$', upload_page, name="upload_page" ),
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^accounts/', include('regfields.urls')),

# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

The code is also on: http://dpaste.com/600444/

Although everything looks fine, the upload always fails.

I use: filename = settings.UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR, where, UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR is definaed in settings.py as '/media/'

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong (Sorry, I am new to web programming and actually never used JS before, but can program in python reasonably!)

Comment: Are you getting the "Bad Upload" 404 that the ajax_upload function raises or a different 404?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thats the problem: I am neither getting a bad upload or a 403/404. When it uploads, it seems to fail on OnComplete and throws the else error. It almost immediately throws the error. Another question for you: Do I need to change anything in the fileuploader.js script?

Comment: No, fileuploader.js should work without any changes.  What browser are you using to test?  If it isn't something that properly supports HTML5 it could be a problem with the iframe fallback.  In the else, if you try printing responseJSON's value what do you get (false, null, etc.)?  As Daniel asked below, are you sure an ajax request is even going out?  You can use Firebug in Firefox (not sure about Chrome or Opera's dev tools) to look at the Ajax traffic after you start the upload.  You can also use Wireshark or Fiddler (Fiddler is easier to use for this purpose) to watch the traffic.

Comment: Alex, Thanks again for your help. I am using Firebox 6 on Ubuntu. I have looked at the firebug output and it does seem to do a post request. I have attached the output on: http://dpaste.com/600871/ It seems to say something like NameError at ajax_upload. Does this point to anything? :(

Comment: Alex, I have also found using Firebug that it seems to say: Exception Location:/home/foo/path/mysite/../mysite/views.py in save_upload, line 45, and line 45 is basically: "filename = settings.UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR" and I have UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR = '/media/' in my settings.py file. An updated output from firebug is on: http://dpaste.com/600879/

Comment: Update: I found that something is strange with the UPLOAD_STORAGE_DIR and therefore, decided to hardcode the path, something like: filename = "/home/foo/path/to/upload". Now, my fire bug output shows me: responseText = {"success": false}.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  The error in your dpaste says "global name 'settings' is not defined" so somewhere you are missing an import of your settings file.

As for the success as false, it sounds like now the method is at least executing, you will have to pinpoint where in the code it is failing.  Once you nail that down I can help you further.

Comment: Alex, it seems to fail at the "onComplete: function( id, fileName, responseJSON )". It throws the "else" error in the if-else loop. I am trying to relate it to fileupload.js file, but not sure what I am looking for! Firebug simply says success:fail.

Comment: Sorry, by "pinpoint where the code is failing" I meant find where in your Django code there is a failure occurring, thus causing it to return a failure to the javascript and exhibiting the behavior you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your Javascript. It should read `{% csrf_token %}` instead of `{{ csrf_token }}`.

**Edit:**
After your comments, I had a closer look at the article you linked.

You need to include the library `fileuploader.js`. It will replace the placeholder div with the id `file-uploader` with a form with the proper event handlers. Creating a form in plain HTML will not work.

I suggest that you have a look at the example in the Github repository: https://github.com/alexkuhl/file-uploader/tree/master/client

Comment: Hi Daniel.. Thanks for that.. I have redid the script (see edit above) without the typo, and I still get the same 404 error :(

Comment: Is an AJAX request made at all? Or a normal form request with a page reload? Also, can you fix the indentation in your python code to make it more readable?

Comment: No, I do not think an AJAX request has been made (could you please explain what you mean here?). I have put the code on dpaste now: dpaste.com/600371 I think something might be wrong in line#40. I wonder what action "" I should use here. Should it be action="ajax_upload" ? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Daniel, thanks so much for your reply. I have now revamped the code, and it looks as follows: http://dpaste.com/600413/ I have basically used the demo.html as the start point, and then changed the javascript portion of the code as per [link] (kuhlit.blogspot.com/2011/04/…) by Alex Kuhl. However, I kinda seem to lose th upload button once I insert the modified JS code. So, I changed the JS code to get document by id to file-uploader-demo1.. but now, when I upload files, it always seems to fail.. Any thoughts as to what I am doing horribly stupid(?) Thanks again for your time

Comment: {% csrf_token %} renders an HTML input widget (and a hidden div) so it's not applicable to javascript. I'd remove it since it is confusing to see it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return True` to the if-statement that checks if it's raw data, otherwise it will return False even if the upload is successful:

```
...
if raw_data:
    foo = uploaded.read(1024)
    while foo:
        dest.write(foo)
        foo = uploaded.read(1024) 
    return True
...
```